# Here Map findpickups Cannot match onto a road link with 1000.0m search radius

Tags: here-api

Hello I try to use api here map for findpickups, I tried to use the same example in the documentation Can you help me thank you

```
https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findpickups.json
?mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
&start=waypoint0;50.115620,8.631210
&departure=2016-10-14T07:30:00+02:00
&vehicleCost=0.29
&driverCost=20
&maxDetour=60
&restTimes=disabled
&end=waypoint3;50.132540,8.649280
&destination0=waypoint1;50.122540,8.631070;pickup:LOAD2
&destination1=waypoint2;50.128920,8.629830;drop:LOAD2,value:200
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And i get this error

```
{"issues":[{"message":"Cannot match 50.11562/8.63121 onto a road link with 1000.0m search radius"}],"error_id":"e4d089f1-c756-4c72-9835-717f522a0350","response_code":"400 Bad Request"}
```

Source : https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-pickup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after contact with the support : I replaced wse with fleet and remove the +02: 00